# Connecting to Bing Maps SDK from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, soap, bing, soap4r

I am attempting to connect to [Bing Maps SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx) through a RoR application.  My goal is to calculate driving distance between two locations after geocoding them.  I am new to SOAP and ROR so I may be making a simple mistake.

Two days of Googling (Binging?) and I'm coming up short.  Here is what I am doing:

### Environment

Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows Vista (getting a Mac next week).
gem install httpclient --source http://dev.ctor.org/download/ 
gem install soap4r --include-dependencies

### Browser Test

Going to https://staging.common.virtualearth.net/find-30/common.asmx?wsdl I am prompted with  User Name and Password.  I can enter both successfully and receive the WSDL file.  So the **URL, userid, and password are correct**.

### Code

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'soap4r'
require 'httpclient'
require "soap/wsdlDriver"
  user = "XXXXXX"
  pass = "XXXXXXX"
  wsdl = "https://staging.common.virtualearth.net/find-30/common.asmx?wsdl"
  driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl).create_rpc_driver
  driver.options["protocol.http.basic_auth"] << [wsdl,user,pass]
```

### Console Output

> > driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl).create_rpc_driver

---

HTTPClient::**BadResponseError: unexpected response**: <#HTTP::Message::Headers:0x4f6cabc @reason_phrase="**Unauthorized**", @request_uri=nil, 
@body_date=nil, @status_code=401, @dumped=false, @request_method=nil, @chunked=false, 
@body_charset=nil, @request_via_proxy=nil, @header_item=[["Connection", "close"], 
["Date", "Thu, 09 Jul 2009 02:53:59 GMT"], ["Server", "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"], 
["P3P", "CP=\"BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo\""], 
["X-Powered-By", "ASP.NET"], ["WWW-Authenticate", "Digest qop=\"auth\", realm=\"
MapPoint\", nonce=\"87b3d5847da867f7930801742100f2e55de88fd216317a696fe1411f79e3\""], 
["Content-Length", "0"]], @body_size=0, @http_version="1.1", @body_type=nil, @request_query=nil, @is_request=false>
from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:840:in `follow_redirect'

### References I've reviewed

Quite possible that one of these has the answer.  I just don't have enough background in SOAP to find it...

http://hideoustriumph.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/ws-deathstar-for-the-rest-of-us/
http://s2.diffuse.it/blog/show/62-Consume_SSL_protected_Web_Services_with_soap4r
http://dev.ctor.org/doc/soap4r/RELEASE_en.html#samples
http://markthomas.org/2007/09/12/getting-started-with-soap4r/
http://www.elctech.com/articles/consuming-soap-with-ruby-and-soap-mapping-object
http://wso2.org/project/wsf/ruby/1.1.0/docs/manual.html
http://www.globalnerdy.com/2009/06/29/learnhub-powered-by-rails-searches-with-bing/
http://rpheath.com/posts/298-consuming-soap-services-in-ruby

Comment: Good discussion on 47hats about the interest in getting another option besides Google Maps.  Bing is an option, but unfortunately the tools just are not there yet.  See the "$10K gotcha":  http://www.47hats.com/?p=1329

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Ruby library [Savon](http://github.com/rubiii/savon), by far the best SOAP client in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

User [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) for handling wsdl and then use geocode to calculate the distance between two points . because bing map API doesn't give the direct '**distance difference**' but it provides us the lat/lng of points . and Geocoder can give the more accurate distance between two pairs of lat/lng